# How many integers are of the form $n/d(n)$, where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series

This was post by me on   [Maths SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680559/all-about-a-failed-conjecture): but it did not get any solution.

Some months ago I made the following conjecture -

Let $d(n)$ denote the number of divisors of $n $.
Then let $N$ be a number such that $d(N)$ divides $N$ . Also let $I= \frac{N}{d(N)}$ which is defined as the "Index of Beauty of $N$ ".
Then, For every number $I$ there exists a number $N$ such that $I$ is the index of beauty of $N$.

This conjecture was proved false by Greg Martin [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620626/proof-on-a-conjecture-involving-dn).

 He said that it can be showed by exaustive computation that the following $I$ fail the conjecture under $1000$ are  $\{18, 27, 30, 45, 63, 64, 72, 99, 105, 112, 117, 144, 153, 160, 162,
165, 171, 195, 207, 225, 243, 252, 255, 261, 279, 285, 288, 294, 320,
333, 336, 345, 352, 360, 369, 387, 396, 405, 416, 423, 435, 441, 465,
468, 477, 490, 504, 531, 544, 549, 555, 567, 576, 603, 608, 612, 615,
616, 625, 639, 645, 657, 684, 705, 711, 726, 728, 735, 736, 747, 792,
795, 801, 810, 828, 840, 873, 880, 885, 891, 909, 915, 927, 928, 936,
952, 960, 963, 981, 992\}$

Now what I am interested is that sequence of $I$ that fails.

(i) Is this sequence infinite?How? 
(ii)Is there any approximation which can tell the number of such failed $I$ less than a fixed $x$ 
(iii)If the sequence is infinite then are there  canonical forms in which all of the values are in our list.

Comment: This question is too basic for mathoverflow. You may find http://oeis.org/A036763 useful, though.

Comment: I disagree - I think this is unlikely to be resolved except through research-level methods, yet it is quite possible that it can be resolved, at least partially. So I think the question fits the parameters for mathoverflow.

Comment: This questions is not too basic for mathoverflow. How can it be so when I can barely even understand the question?

Comment: @GregMartin: In that case I'll answer it.

Comment: Since this question now has 4 close votes, I wish to say that I agree with Greg Martin that the question seems perfectly fine for MO.  I don't know how many exceptional $I$ there are up to $x$, and it seems not easy.  Naturally there may be many opinions on the interest of the question, but perhaps that applies to many problems on MO.

Answer (score 16):

Here's an elementary argument proving that the set of numbers $I$ that fail the conjecture is infinite.

**Claim.** $p^{17} \in I$ for all primes $p > 19$.

**Proof.** Suppose that $p^{17}=\frac{N}{d(N)}$ for some $N$.  Write $N=p^{17+k}n$ where $p$ does not divide $n$.  Then, $d(N)=(18+k)d(n)$, and so $p^kn=(18+k)d(n)$. Since $p>19$ and $n \geq d(n)$ this can only hold if $k=0$.  But now $\frac{n}{d(n)}=18$, which Greg Martin has shown is impossible.

Comment: Here is a variant of your construction which produces many excluded numbers.  I claim that if $p$ (a prime) is large then $15p$ fails the conjecture.  For if $n=15pd(n)$ and $p$ is large then $p$ can divide $n$ only to the power $1$ (use $d(n)\le n^{1/3}$ for large $n$).  If now $n=pm$ with $(p,m)=1$ then we must have $m=30d(m)$, contradicting Greg Martin's result that $30$ is excluded.  In fact, inspecting his table it looks like $15p$ is excluded for all primes $p>5$.

Comment: @Lucia extremely good proof

Comment: @Lucia can you prove that if the number in the list is in the form $15n$ then $n$ is a prime.

Comment: @ShivamPatel:  Not true -- $810$, $840$, $960$ etc.  I'm afraid I don't know any more about this sequence!

Comment: @Lucia sorry ..I did not see the list ...just as a curiosity so can you tell me the distribution of numbers in form $10n$ in the sequence

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple consequence of the density of refactorable numbers, http://oeis.org/A033950, and the growth of the divisor function. Basically, $n/d(n)>x$ if $x>n^{1+\frac{0.7}{\log\log n}}$ (where the constant could be anything greater than $\log 2$) with only finitely many exceptions. But of these numbers only

$$
O\left(\frac{(\log\log x)^{k^3-1}}{\log x}\right)=\\
O\left(\frac{(\log(\log n+\frac{0.7\log n}{\log\log n}))^{k^3-1}}{\log n+\frac{0.7\log n}{\log\log n}}\right)=\\
O\left(\frac{(\log\log n)^{k^3-1}}{\log n}\right)
$$

are refactorable (for every $k>1$), so there must be infinitely many exceptions. Further, these 'exceptions' have density 1 (though the constants are nasty).

Comment: Hmm.  n/ something bigger than 1 is bigger than x if x is bigger than n times something else bigger than 1.  One of us is doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your argument.  What exactly are you claiming about the set of numbers of the form $n/d(n)$?

Comment: All the $+$ should be $-$.

Comment: And the second inequality needs to read the other way round, that is, $x<n^{1-0.7/\log\log n}$.

Comment: The argument claims that the exceptions have density 1; I don't think that is true.

Comment: @Lucia: A slightly weaker claim would be that their density is 0.

Comment: @Charles: I think your argument is unclear and possibly flawed -- at least I haven't understood it.  Could you write it carefully -- it has several typos, and the second part of it seems unclear to me.